Why isn't MemberQ working?
    term=1;
    CheckDuplicate={};(* keeping inside this all the terms that are already inside term *)
    k=1;
    While[k <= SizesPerTermInPolynomial[[j]],
    
        var=x[RandomInteger[{1,NoOfVariables}]];
        Print["var \n",var];

        if[MemberQ[CheckDuplicate,var],   (* memberq return true if it matches..*)
            continue[];
        ] 
        (* if var which is x[random] is not in term already (or in checkduplicate) then multiply it with term... *)
        term=term*var;
        Print["term \n",term];

        AppendTo[CheckDuplicate,var];  (* include var for the variables that are over(already there) in this current term *)
        Print["CheckDuplicate \n",CheckDuplicate];

        k++;
    ]

i'm checking for var in checkduplicate if it is present , :it should skip this iteration and continue to the next iteration.. but what i see in the output is::
var x[22]
term 1
CheckDuplicate {x[26], x[3], x[6], x[36], x[39], x[34], x[5], x[8], x[22]}
x[6] is already present!!!
var x[6]  <-- this new variable is an x[6]
term 1
CheckDuplicate {x[26], x[3], x[6], x[36], x[39], x[34], x[5], x[8], x[22], x[6]}
it adds it here at the end
i even tried ContainsQ and ConatinsAll but it isn't working
and also this..
 if[!MemberQ[CheckDuplicate,var],  
    term=term*var;
    AppendTo[CheckDuplicate,var];  
    k++;
   ]

im doing this in Jupyter using the Wolfram Engine,(i started today).

Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. If you have started learning Mathematica, then you will find that the introductory book written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a fast intro for math students as well as a fast intro for programmers to choose from.

thanks alot....!!

Please explore the Tally function.

There are too many syntax errors and missing definitions for us to help you with this code. For example, built in functions are capitalized, so your if and continue are not doing what you expect. Also, I think you're missing a ;. And while we could replace your missing definitions (e.g. SizesPerTermInPolynomial, j, NoOfVariables), it might be the case that whatever definitions you've supplied are themselves causing problems.

As the code seems to suggest, you want to construct list of variable of monomials in polynomials.
As always in Mathematica, a loop construct is inefficient, difficult to control and lengthy by logical decision trees, that are not readable without comments.
Get the variable list by extracting all symbols
var=Union[Cases[polynomial,_Symbol,\[Infinity]]]

You can use subscripted variables e.g. $x_k$ for simplicity
  var=Union[Cases[polynomial,Subscript[x,_],\[Infinity]]]

Get e.g.  a table of entries and their positions by mapping the desired object list as a pure function into the variables list
 ({ # ,  Position[polynomial,#]}  &) /@ var

With such a list you may play around to analyze connections between the monomials in the sum representing the polynomial.
